# Please clarify how Knowledge Pool for Magus Archetype - Extempresario works?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> **[Knowledge Pool (Su)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-fans-united/extempresario/)**
>
> At 7th level, when an extempresario rests, she can expend a number of points from her [arcane pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Arcane-Pool-Su-) up to her Charisma bonus to temporarily add additional spells known, chosen from the standard magus spell list. Adding a spell to the extempresario’s spells known for the day costs a number of points from her arcane pool equal to the spell level. For each point expended, she gains 1 spell level worth of spells. For example, if she spends 4 points, she may chose two 2nd level spells, or one 1st level and one 3rd level spell. She cannot use knowledge pool to gain a higher level spell than she can cast. A cantrip is treated as 1 spell level. She treats these temporary spells as if they were spells she normally knows, retaining them until she next rests, when they are forgotten. She casts these temporary spells as any other spell known, including casting them using her spell reserves ability. However, she may not expend addition points to add metamagic arcana effects to these temporarily known spells.

When rest is mentioned, is the 8 hour rest where you regain spells per day back? What then happens to the Arcane Pool points (APP) spent, you don't regain all your AP or do you.

Ex: Arcane Pool = 15 and Cha 20/+5
During rest 5 APP used add one 2nd and one 3rd level spell to users Spells Known list for a day. User rest and regain spells used the day/(8 hours before) and two new spells via APP. Does the user start that day/(8 hours later) with his Arcane Pool maxed or with five less APP till the spells added prior are forgotten?

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's a direct adaptation of the regular [Knowledge Pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Knowledge-Pool-Su-) for a CHA-based spontaneous caster, that no time is given (like "rest for an hour") and that the spells are added "for the day" and "until she next rests", I think that the rest is the 8 hours one.

The wording is a bit unclear on the AP cost, but I would say it's spent for the day, if only because the ability could have been written without talking about spending AP if not.